# How to forward a media file in Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp, email

I want to download a media file from my email attachment and later forward the same from my whatsapp account. I am not able to view my downloaded media file. How do I forward the file from my whatsapp account?

Comment: "I want to download a media file from my email attachment", you downloaded from email app or browser?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download an application that works like a file manager from the Store.
I suggest you to download "Files". Thanks to this app, you can search every file in your phone. Probably, your media file is in the "Download" directory.